# How can I set the shell used for debugging in VS Code in launch.json?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In my VS Code Node.js project's launch.json config, I'm trying to set the shell to cmd.exe rather than the default.  Is that possible?

I know I can set it globally via `terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows` in preferences, but in this case I want to change it just in a single debug launch task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's an internal terminal being used for your launch config, try using the `terminal.integrated.automationProfile.<platform>` settings (it's a setting- not a launch config property, so in general, it will affect all launch configs for the scope that the setting applies to). You can set it in a user or workspace [settings.json file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson). You can verify that the shell you specified is being used by selecting your launch config, starting run/debug, and then opening VS Code's builtin process explorer and looking for your program (use `Developer: Open Process Explorer` in the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)).

If there's no internal terminal being used, then I think you might be out of luck. Check if the specific launch config schema you're working with has properties to select a wrapping shell. Maybe no wrapping shell is being used at all. You can also check that using the builtin process explorer.

For example, I'm on an Ubuntu system, and I put `"terminal.integrated.automationProfile.linux": { "path": "/usr/bin/dash" }` in my workspace .vscode/settings.json file, and then created a NodeJS launch config. If I don't change the `console` property, it defaults to `"internalConsole"`, and I can see in the process explorer that it doesn't run (directly) under a shell at all. If I instead put `"console": "internalConsole",` in the launch config, it will honour what I put in `terminal.integrated.automationProfile.<platform>` (in the process explorer, I see `ptyHost` -> `/.../dash` -> `/.../node test.js`).